# How to reset React component to start from initial state from inside the parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
var A = React.createClass({
onTabChange:function(e, id){
    this.setState( {tabIndex:id} );
    //Inside this function I would like to get the state of B component 
    //to start from initial state, (i.e. call initialState() function)
},

render:function(){
    return <div>
        <FormTabs options={['A', 'B', 'C']} onChange={this.onTabChange} value={this.state.tabIndex} /> // This creates 3 simple tabs 
        <B x={5} y={8} z={10} />
    </div>;
}
```

});

```
var B = React.createClass({
getInitialState:function(){
    return {
        x: a,
        y: b,
        z: c
    }
},

render:function(){
    this.state.x = this.props.x;
    this.state.y = this.props.y;
    this.state.z = this.props.z;

    return <div>
            //...
        </div>
}
```

});

So, what I exactly want is to delete the instance of B component inside the onTabChange function. Any helps about how I can delete the instance of it so that when I call , it gets into B.initialState() function.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the use case? You are approaching this with a mutative solution, but I'm sure there is a more declarative "react like" way to solve your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

So the way you're asking this is a bit confusing, but if I am understanding you correctly what you're looking to do is rerender B when onTabChange function is called using B's getInitialState. One way you could do this is by passing x, y, z as a single object (i.e. }{x:5,y:8,z:10}. Then in you're getInitialState you can check if that prop is set, if it is return that prop as initialState, if not return abc. So it would look like:

```
var A = React.createClass({
onTabChange:function(e, id){
    this.setState( {tabIndex:id} );
    ReactDOM.render(<B />, document.getElementById("bContainer));
},

render:function(){
var values= {x:5,y:8,z:10};
return <div>
    <FormTabs options={['A', 'B', 'C']} onChange={this.onTabChange} value={this.state.tabIndex} /> // This creates 3 simple tabs 
    <div id="bContainer">
        <B values={values} />
    </div>
</div>;
}});

var B = React.createClass({
   getInitialState:function(){
      if (this.props.values !== undefined) {
          return this.props.values
      }
      return {
         x: a,
         y: b,
         z: c
       }
   },   

   render:function(){
      //this.state.x = this.props.x;
      //this.state.y = this.props.y;
      //this.state.z = this.props.z;

      return <div>
          //...
         </div>
      }
   };
});
```

Then you can just use the state variables directly in your B render.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I knew that I could use state variables. I admit that the question was a bit non-clearly explained. it is solved anyways.

Comment: @NaibBaghirov Was this the answer you were looking for or did you solve it a different way?

Comment: No actually, your answer is kind of not correct because B component was getting rendered again in my original code too. What I wanted to happen is to somehow unmount the B component or delete all the instances of it so that when I render it after "onTabChange" function, it defaults its values to initial state value. I solved the problem by kinda workaround way which is not the best solution probably, but it works and that is what I wanted. Thank you for your effort to answer the question tho.